# QGIS documentation in French?

Tags: qgis, pyqt, documentation, french

I am working on a plugin in qgis and i have to make a document from A to Z about that but on French . and I am looking now for some documentation of python,QT , pyqt4, and QGIS in French.

Answer (score 1):

#### For QGIS

there is:

- The [Francophone OSGeo Chapter](http://osgeo.asso.fr/) ([Wiki OSGeo: Francophone OSGeo Chapter](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Francophone_OSGeo_Chapter)) is in charge of all the translations (softwares, documentation, site [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/fr/site/) in French) with a mailing list `francophone@lists.osgeo.org` that is visible at [Nabble OSGeo French Local Chapter](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/OSGeo-French-Local-Chapter-f3726325.html). It organises the [FOSS4G-FR](http://www.foss4g.fr/) event.

There are two forums:

- [Forum SIG: SIG Libre/ Open source](http://www.forumsig.org/forumdisplay.php/86-SIG-Libre-Open-Source)
- [Georezo: Le coin de l'Open Source](http://georezo.net/forum/index.php)

Some Portals/blogs as:

- [Portail SIG](http://www.portailsig.org/)
- [Geotribu](http://geotribu.net/)
- [Le coin de l'open-source géospatial](http://georezo.net/blog/geolibre/)
- and others

#### For Python, PyQt4, ...

Just search on the on the web (many, many results...)

Comment: thakss sooo much :)